Could the presence of Alkali Metals in recycled hydrated cement paste (HCP) affect the quality of the clinker?
"Electric recycling of Portland cement at scale" is an article that describes a new process for producing cement from recycled concrete and steel scrap. This process could significantly reduce CO2 emissions from cement production. The article specifically mentions,

A widely available high-volume source of decarbonated calcium is found in the hydrated cement paste embedded in used concrete. It has been known for a long time that it is possible, in principle, to reclinker hydrated cement paste (HCP). However, there are several challenges to applying this process in a conventional kiln when a large fraction of hydrated cement paste is used. The presence of sulfates (added as set retardant during production) increases the belite content of the reclinkered cement at the expense of highly reactive alite. Furthermore, sulfates are volatile and will condense in cooler parts of the kiln system, causing operational difficulties. Nonetheless, there exist commercial offerings of cement made with partly replaced raw meal (such as Holcim GeoCycle). Separately, cement recovered from used concrete can contain a high fraction of chlorides that, if retained, would exclude the use of reclinkered cement in reinforced applications

My question was that, the article highlights the potential challenges posed by sulfates and chlorides on clinker formation during the recycling process in the electric-arc furnace (EAF). However, since the recycled hydrated cement paste (HCP) originates from demolished concrete, won't it retain various components from the original cementitious materials, including alkali metals such as sodium (Na) and potassium (K).
How might the presence of theses alkali metals in small amounts in the HCP specifically affect the clinker formation process within the EAF environment? Or would this not be a probelm?
Furthermore, are there any other materials/compounds that might be present in HCPs that can affect the final clinker?
